# How to give goal using robot localization

Tags: ros, gps, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've setup the `move_base` and and `robot_localization`  and I'm getting `Datum UTM coordinate is (483236.261047, 6674529.600528)` when i launch the localization file.

How to know who's publishing these values and how to publish these values to move_base?

I created robot_localization files referring to husky's files

I've read that I have to convert LLto utm but why it's giving me utm values

edit:
launch file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

  <group ns="gps_nav"> 
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find sk_navigation)/params/ekf_params.yaml" />
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find sk_navigation)/params/navsat_params_sim.yaml" />

  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_se_odom" clear_params="true"/>

  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_se_map" clear_params="true">
    <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="odometry/filtered_map"/>
  </node>

  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node" name="navsat_transform" clear_params="true" output="screen" >
      <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="odometry/filtered_map"/>
      <remap from="gps/fix" to="/sk/gps/fix"/>
      <remap from="/imu/data" to="/sk/imu"/>
  </node>
  </group>

</launch>
```

params

```
ekf_se_odom:
  frequency: 30
  sensor_timeout: 0.1
  two_d_mode: true
  transform_time_offset: 0.0
  transform_timeout: 0.0
  print_diagnostics: true
  debug: false

  map_frame: map
  odom_frame: odom
  base_link_frame: base_link
  world_frame: odom

# -------------------------------------
# Wheel odometry:

  odom0: /odom
  odom0_config: [false, false, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 true,  true,  true,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false]
  odom0_queue_size: 10
  odom0_nodelay: true
  odom0_differential: false
  odom0_relative: false

# --------------------------------------
# imu configure:

  imu0: /sk/imu
  imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                true,  true,  false,
                false, false, false,
                true,  true,  true,
                true,  true,  true]
  imu0_nodelay: false
  imu0_differential: false
  imu0_relative: false
  imu0_queue_size: 10
  imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

  use_control: false
  use_control: false

  process_noise_covariance: [1e-3, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    1e-3, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    1e-3, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.5,   0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0.5,   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0.1,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3]

  initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,   0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1.0,   0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1.0,   0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1.0,  0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1.0,  0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1.0]

ekf_se_map:
  frequency: 30
  sensor_timeout: 0.1
  two_d_mode: true
  transform_time_offset: 0.0
  transform_timeout: 0.0
  print_diagnostics: true
  debug: false

  map_frame: map
  odom_frame: odom
  base_link_frame: base_link
  world_frame: map

# -------------------------------------
# Wheel odometry:

  odom0: /odom
  odom0_config: [false, false, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 true,  true,  true,
                 false, false, true,
                 false, false, false]
  odom0_queue_size: 10
  odom0_nodelay: true
  odom0_differential: false
  odom0_relative: false

# -------------------------------------
# GPS odometry:

  odom1: /sk/gps/fix
  odom1_config: [true,  true,  false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false]
  odom1_queue_size: 10
  odom1_nodelay: true
  odom1_differential: false
  odom1_relative: false

# --------------------------------------
# imu configure:

  imu0: /sk/imu
  imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                true,  true, false,
                false, false, false,
                true,  true,  true,
                true,  true,  true]
  imu0_nodelay: true
  imu0_differential: false
  imu0_relative: false
  imu0_queue_size: 10
  imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

  use_control: false

  process_noise_covariance: [1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    1e-3, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.5,   0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0.5,   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0.1,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3]

  initial_estimate_covariance: [1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,   0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1.0,   0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1.0,   0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1.0,  0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1.0,  0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1.0]
```

topics
/gps_nav/gps/filtered
/gps_nav/imu/data
/gps_nav/odometry/filtered
/gps_nav/odometry/filtered_map
/gps_nav/odometry/gps
/gps_nav/set_pose

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349880/how-to-give-goal-using-robot-localization/) by [me_saw](https://answers.ros.org/users/52338/me_saw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2020-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actual navigation of the robot is handled by move_base. You will give position goals to move_base and move_base will provide velocity goals to your controller to bring your robot to the final pose without colliding into obstacles. `robot_localization` is a package used to obtain an accurate estimate of your current position by applying a kalman filter over it. Ensuring the GPS data is in UTM format is crucial since it follows the ROS ENU standard. If you want to know who is publishing what, please use [rqt_graph](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_graph) and it will display the relationship between topics and ros nodes.

In move_base, you have to configure the odometry data by using ROS transform frames. If your GPS was published in a `map` to `base_link` frame, you can specify `map` as the global frame and `base_link` as the robot frame in move_base config file. move_base will use this information along with any costmap provided to navigate.

---

Originally posted by [hashirzahir](https://answers.ros.org/users/53034/hashirzahir/) with karma: 228 on 2020-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [me_saw](https://answers.ros.org/users/52338/me_saw/) on 2020-04-20**:
can you show me a example of `robot_localization` `rqt_grpah` so that i can have an idea how it shoukd it look

**Comment by [hashirzahir](https://answers.ros.org/users/53034/hashirzahir/) on 2020-04-20**:
The robot_localization node should take in 1 or 2 sensor data such as `sensor_msgs::IMU` from your IMU and maybe `nav_msgs::Odometry` from your GPS publisher. The `robot_localization` node will publish 1 topic, something like `/odom/filtered`. If you are not sure what your node is doing, you can do `rosnode list` on the command line and `rosnode info NODE_NAME` whatever you want to see. As mentioned, ideally, robot_localization will take in a few topics from your different sensors (in the correct ENU orientation) and output 1 filtered odometry topic that is a good localization estimate of your robot. Please check [here](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/state_estimation_nodes.html#published-topics) to see the published topics of `robot_localization`

**Comment by [me_saw](https://answers.ros.org/users/52338/me_saw/) on 2020-04-20**:
I referred to husky robot's localization to configure my files and I'm getting so many topics so I'm confused which what

I've edited the question and the params please check it once

**Comment by [hashirzahir](https://answers.ros.org/users/53034/hashirzahir/) on 2020-04-20**:
First of all, why do you have 2 nodes   `<node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_se_odom" clear_params="true"/>` running? ekf_se_odom and ekf_se_map. The data sources are exactly the same for odom0 and imu0 so why do you need 2 nodes?

**Comment by [me_saw](https://answers.ros.org/users/52338/me_saw/) on 2020-04-20**:
I thought for map i should another node

so it's not required?

**Comment by [hashirzahir](https://answers.ros.org/users/53034/hashirzahir/) on 2020-04-20**:
What is the map frame for in your use case? Traditionally, ROS follows map -> odom -> base_link where odom->base_link is the dead-reckoning based estimation that is used for low level controls. It updates at a high frequency. map->odom is a correction provided by some algorithm (say SLAM or GPS) to fix the finalized odometry if the GPS updates at a slow rate. Please explain what is your use case and what is your TF tree. What is your end goal?

**Comment by [me_saw](https://answers.ros.org/users/52338/me_saw/) on 2020-04-20**:
I'm using gps and I want to know the current position of my robot and i want to input gps coordinates as goal to move_base to move to a certain position

**Comment by [me_saw](https://answers.ros.org/users/52338/me_saw/) on 2020-04-20**:
i got /odom/filter its giving me the twist and pose values what are these values how to use these values move to a certain position by giving it to move_base

and I'm also launching navsat_transform its publishing two topics what are they and how to them

**Comment by [hashirzahir](https://answers.ros.org/users/53034/hashirzahir/) on 2020-04-20**:
Please read the documentation on [Odometry message](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html). It clearly states what is twist (speed) and pose (position). As long as this is correct, move_base can work correctly. You dont need to use robot_localization as your start point. Just create a simple publisher that publishes the TF from map -> base_link and an Odometry message over some topic using GPS alone.